# Puppet cluster configuration in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, puppet

Puppet is appending the EC2 DNS name with the host name in the configuration file, I am not able to create puppet cluster as client is not able to connect with master.

Comment: What is your question? Even if this was a question, there is not nearly enough information provided to give a solid answer.

Comment: I want to create a puppet cluster making changes in the host files, as I am using AWS , how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the comlete hostname of the system is taken into consideration, what puppet does is it appends the FQDN with the host name.

You may get it by typing in command

> hostname --fqdn

this will give you the exact string that is added to your machine's hosts name. For exact solution append this "string " into the host name by

> hostname localhost."string"